# Class variable gets implicitly casted to int despite explicit cast

Tags: c++

I wrote implicit cast operator to double and explicit cast operator to int in foo class, and function that takes int as an argument. Despite of being called with not casted foo object code gets executed.

I used gcc **PRETTY_FUNCTION** and found out that foo object gets casted to double then to int.

```
class foo
{
public:
    int x, y;
    foo(int x, int y) : x{x}, y{y} {}
    explicit operator int() {cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return x/y;}
    operator double() {cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; return double(x)/double(y);}
};

void printint(int x)
{
    cout << x << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    foo var(1,2);
    printint(var);
}
```

I expected this not to compile because of explicit operator, but instead it does and prints 0 as int(1/2).

Output of program is: 
foo::operator double()
0

Comment: Then what for is the explicit operator if class object can get casted to something implicitly and then cast to int, shouldn't it prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 10):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1) zero or one standard conversion sequence;
>
> 2) zero or one user-defined conversion;
>
> 3) zero or one standard conversion sequence.

Hence your `foo` can be converted to a `double` (2) and then the `double` is converted to an `int` (3).

If you want the code to not compile you have to also make the `double` conversion `explicit`. The `explicit` only prevents your `foo` to convert to a `int` in step 2 alone, but in the whole sequence the conversion can still be done implicitly. Implicit conversion can be tricky and becaue of (1) and (3) a single user provided implicit conversion (2) can have unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 0):

of course it will use the `double` conversion operator and then cast the `double` to a `int`. the `double` conversion operator can implicitly be called. Remove `explicit` and it won't cast to `double` first

It can't use the `explicit operator int()` because of the `explicit`

Comment: Isn't purpose of the explicit cast operator preventing object from being casted to int unless I don't state that in code?

Comment: @doromaanim if that were the only conversation possible, yes. But since your class can be implicitly converted to `double`, and `double` can be implicitly converted to `int`, that is what the compiler chooses to do. Your `explicit` has no effect on that second conversion since it doesn't involve your class